# python 3.3 on sublime text 2 windows 7

Tags: sublimetext2, python-3.3

I am running windows 7 32 bit and i am using sublime text 2 I want to know how can I change the default python in ST2 to the python 3.3 I down loaded. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Sublime build system for Python. Copy the `Python.sublime-build` file from the `Packages/Python` folder to the `Packages/User` folder. In the file in the `User` folder, change the `cmd` option from `python` to `c:/python33/python` (where your Python 3.3 executable is located).